# Passing parameters in a MATLAB function handle

Tags: matlab, function, handle

I have to solve my differential equation with `ode45`:

```
[t, phi]=ode45(@diff_phi, time_period, initial);
```

where diff_phi is my function:

```
function dphi_dt = diff(t,phi,gamma0,gamma1,L0,L1)
phi0=phi(1);
phi1=phi(2);

dphi0_dt=-2*L0*phi0-gamma0*(phi0^2+1);
dphi1_dt=-2*L1*phi1-gamma1*(phi1^2+1);

dphi_dt=[dphi0_dt; dphi1_dt];
end
```

This way is not working:

```
[t, phi]=ode45(@(t,phi) diff_phi(gamma0,gamma1,L0,L1), time_period, initial);
```

because I got this error message:

```
Attempted to access phi(2); index out of bounds because numel(phi)=1.

Error in diff_phi (line 18)
phi1=phi(2);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff_phi` still expects 6 parameters, so in your second method, try:

```
[t, phi]=ode45(@(t,phi) diff_phi(t,phi,gamma0,gamma1,L0,L1), time_period, initial);
```